# replace ID in path dredd hooks

Tags: python, swagger, dredd

I have this dredd.yml config file:

```
paths:
  "/network":
    get:
      produces:
      - application/json;charset=utf-8
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Ok 
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/NetworkResponse"
  "/network/{id}":
    get:
      produces: 
        - application/json;charset=utf-8
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        description: id
        required: true
        type: string
        enum: 
          - "net-76faddf092e62151"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Ok
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/NetworkIdResponse"
```

I want to replace `{id}` in path with python dredd hooks. 
I tried so:

```py
import json
import dredd_hooks as hooks

response_stash = {}

@hooks.after("Networks > ALL ")
def save_network_id_to_stash(transaction):
    # save HTTP response with IDs to the stash
    response_stash[transaction['id']] = transaction['id']
    print(transaction['id'])

@hooks.before("Networks > ID")
def add_network_id_to_request(transaction):
    parsed_body = json.loads(response_stash['Networks > ALL'])
    network_id = parsed_body['id']
    transaction['fullPath'] = transaction['fullPath'].replace('net-76faddf092e62151', network_id)
```

Test execution was successful , but only with 1 id. 
Answer from 1st operation outputs a list with objects, where are ids in ['id']. 
How to replace `{id}` in path and make tests for all networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@hooks.before("Networks > ID > 200 > application/json;charset=utf-8)
```

it is the correct definition of the hook name.

You can see all variables `transaction['real']` , `transaction['name']` and so one with
`print(transaction)` within hook function.